# ContainerAware and Session

Tags: serialization, symfony, containers, symfony-2.1

I'm using a custom class that extends `ContainerAware`, and I need to serialize it to store it in the session.

I'm using `__sleep` and `__wakeup` to select what properties of my object needs to persist in session, and of course I'm not storing the `$this->container` in the session.

So my problem is : when I use `__wakeup` , I don't have access to my container anymore! Is there a way I can handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yeah that would be the expected outcome. If You have your class registered as service im not sure it that would be possible, because on __wakeup you woudl have to execute setContainer with correct container argument.